# Hibernate query grouping by column

Tags: hibernate

I'm developing an API REST using Jersey and Hibernate. I have this table in the database:

CODDOMINIO | CODIGO | DESCRIPCION

(CODDOMINIO, CODIGO) is the composite PK.

I want to return a json with this structure:

```
[
     {CODDOMINIO: "1", 
      CODIGOS: [
          {CODIGO: "12", DESCRIPCION: "example"},
          {CODIGO: "13", DESCRIPCION: "example"}]},
     {CODDOMINIO: "2", 
      CODIGOS: [
          {CODIGO: "14", DESCRIPCION: "example"},
          {CODIGO: "15", DESCRIPCION: "example"}]},
]
```

and so on... Is there a way to make this automatically by hibernate annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could try to map to a HashMap, or any kind of Java collection that allows control over how the keys and values of that collection are mapped (documentation on mapping collections [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-indexed)) - I think the best option would be to map a collection `Map<EntityPK, SomeValue>` - map the composite PK as key value of the collection.

Second, if you want to have different output for that collection (like the output you provided) you could declare a `@Transient` collection and manipulate theoutput as it suits you. You can find examples on the hibernate documentation on [transient properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-property), and if you google it, you'll find several examples on how to work with transient properties on hibernate.